# having trouble displaying an image on JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, netbeans

Hi i've tried to display an image on jsp but failing miserably. Im generating a chart and saving a the file than refreshing it, now i want to show this picture called chart on jsp. i know this is all on jsp and i should have used servlet but this is just a prototype.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.Color"%>
<%
    String query = "SELECT product_name,price from client";
    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "rootroot", "rootroot");
 //"jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot"
    dataset.executeQuery(query);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Products Vs Price",
            "product_name", "price", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.green);
    try {
        ChartUtilities
                .saveChartAsJPEG(
                        new File(
                                "C:\\Users\\student\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebForm\\WebForm-war\\chart.jpg"),
                        chart, 1000, 1000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem in creating chart.");
    }
%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function refreshIMG()  
 {  
 $.ajax({  
   url: "displaychartpricevsprice.jsp",     cache: false,  
   success: function(html){   $("#").html("<img src=\"C:\Users\student\Desktop\WebForm\WebForm-war\\chart.jpg"/>");  
     callback();  
   }  
 });  
 }  
 function callback()  
 {  
 settimeout("refreshIMG();", 1800000);  
 //1800= 30seconds in ms  
 }  
 refreshIMG();  
 </script>


 </head>
<body>
<div >
<img src="C:\Users\student\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebForm\WebForm-war\chart.jpg"    width=1000 height=1000>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `file://` (or try - `file:///`) at the beginning of the image source URL.

Comment: i have tried <img src="file://C:\Users\student\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebForm\WebForm-war\chart.jpg"    width=1000 height=1000> and <img src="file://C:\Users\student\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebForm\WebForm-war\chart.jpg"    width=1000 height=1000>  still not showing image

Comment: What does your browser say in dev console? Maybe it rejects because of security.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with syntax.You are generating that image and trying to display it on same page.

The only problem I can see is that image is not available when page loads.Try to create that image before the page loads or use ajax if you want to display it after page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Store the image in your web app directory and use either relative url in your image tag

```
<img src="<folder>/chart.jpg"/>
```

or you can use an el expression

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/<folder>/chart.jpg">
```